# Do I need to install SQL Express if SQL Server is already installed?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a server that has SQL Server 2008 R2 installed but my application uses SQL Express 2008 R2 - do I need to install SQL Express as well? The error Im currently getting is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Comment: That error implies you are probably using an incorrect connection string. Had the same problem in a EF deployment the other day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your database the SQL Server and connect with the correct [connection string](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008). You can not attach your Database files like in SQL Server express though.

There is no need to install SQL Server Express.

A common connection string to connect to SQL Server is:

```
Data Source=yourServer;Initial Catalog=yourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Replace `yourServer` with the servername (in the form of Server\instance) and `yourDatabase` with the name of the database you wish to connect to.

The following connection string for SQL Server Express does not work on a standard SQL Server:

```
Server=yourServer;AttachDbFilename=c:\data\yourDatabase.mdf;Database=yourDatabase; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```